# Why is this jQuery not working on my Sharepoint page?

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox, sharepoint-2010, web-parts

I have this code at the bottom of my Sharepoint WebPart's .ascx file:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("The ready function has been reached");
    $('#ckbxEmp').on("change", function () {
        if ($('#ckbxEmp').prop("checked")) {
            alert("Checked");
        } else {
            alert("Not checked");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

On running the WebPart (opening a page that has the WebPart embedded in it), I see the "The ready function has been reached" alert, but on clicking the checkbox, there is no alert.

The checkbox is created like so in the corresponding .ascx.cs file:

```
var ckbxEmployeeQ = new CheckBox
{
    CssClass = "finaff-webform-field-input",
    ID = "ckbxEmp"
};
```

It works in a jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/jy6t5oru/3/):

I also tried changing the code in the .ascx file to this:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("The ready function has been reached");
});

$('#ckbxEmp').on("change", function () {
    if ($('#ckbxEmp').prop("checked")) {
        alert("Checked");
    } else {
        alert("Not checked");
    }
});
</script>
```

...thinking that maybe I needed to make the event handler separate from the "ready" function, but it makes no difference - still doesn't display any response to a change/click of the check box.

Why not?

### UPDATE

I tried SouXin's code, but I still only see "The ready function has been reached" - clicking the checkbox shows me neither "Checked" nor "Not Checked"

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("The ready function has been reached");

    $(document).on("change", '#ckbxEmp', function () {
        if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
            alert("Checked");
        } else {
            alert("Not checked");
        }
    }); 
});
```

...then this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("The ready function has been reached");
});

$(document).on("change", '#ckbxEmp', function () {
    if ($('#ckbxEmp').prop("checked")) {
        alert("Checked");
    } else {
        alert("Not checked");
    }
});
```

...and finally this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("The ready function has been reached");

    $(document).on("change", '#ckbxEmp', function () {
        if ($('#ckbxEmp').prop("checked")) {
            alert("Checked");
        } else {
            alert("Not checked");
        }
    }); 
});
```

...but get the same exact (half-encouraging, half-discouraging) results each time.

### UPDATE 2

Redi to pursue any clue, I followed Claudio's suggestion and "Viewed Source".

I found that, besides being found in the jQuery verbatim, "ckbxEmp" is also embedded within a monstrously long "Welsh" prefix, where that monstrosity (which makes Frankenstein look like Jessica Alba) does triple-duty, for "id", "name", and "for":

```
<td><span class="finaff-webform-field-input"><input id="ctl00_ctl24_g_1caf4ad1_092d_4224_bd10_28ab028aab50_ctl00_ckbxEmp" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$ctl24$g_1caf4ad1_092d_4224_bd10_28ab028aab50$ctl00$ckbxEmp" /><label for="ctl00_ctl24_g_1caf4ad1_092d_4224_bd10_28ab028aab50_ctl00_ckbxEmp">Employee?</label></span></td>
```

So that leads to [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30606652/can-i-access-a-control-by-the-last-portion-of-its-id-in-jquery).

### UPDATE 3

The working solution is a combination of SoulXin's and the answer referenced above ("another question" link). To be terse, the id, since it has been Welshified, has to be found this way: [id$=ckbxEmp]

Comment: Have you checked your generated html to see if there is an element with id `ckbxEmp`? asp.net normally changes ids when send html to client

Comment: I will czech that; but if that is the case, will it always be the same thing, or is it "mystery meat" - this ID this time, that ID the next time, etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It usually happens when you created elements dynamically.
Try this:

```
$(document).on("change", '#ckbxEmp', function () {
   if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
       alert("Checked");
   } else {
       alert("Not checked");
   }
});
```

Take a look on [Direct and delegated events](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

**UPDATE:**

Full code:

```
<script>
 $(document).on("change", '#ckbxEmp', function () {
   console.log('Function has been reached');
   if ($(this).is(":checked")) { //better
       alert("Checked");
   } else {
       alert("Not checked");
   }
 }); 
</script>
```

By the way, better use `console.log('test')` instead of alert. 
Moreover take a look on the 1st comment to your post. ASP changes id on client side. Instead of `#ckbxEmp` possible you need: `<%= ckbxEmp.ClientID %>`

Comment: Don't put this code inside `$(document).ready` It's separate construction.

Comment: I did try that (second ("then this") example in the Update). I think the problem is that the id, name, and "for" (whatever that is) of the Checkbox is actually "ctl00_ctl24_g_1caf4ad1_092d_4224_bd10_28ab028aab50_ctl00_ckbxEmp" not simply "ckbxEmp" (see Update 2)

Comment: Use jquery selector for dynamic id like '$("id$='ckbxEmp'")'